# Strange problem with array order after explode

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string, which I convert into an array using an explode, but when I consult it, it does not come out in the proper order and I have even tried to make it an asort.

```
$clasipun = explode(",","0.11111111111111,0.22222222222222,0.33333333333333");
echo $clasipun[1]; //Receive 0.33333333333333
asort($clasipun);
echo $clasipun[1]; //Receive 0.33333333333333
$stringclasi = implode ("," $clasipun);
echo $stringclasi; //"0.11111111111111,0.22222222222222,0.33333333333333"
```

I have tried with some tricks, but dont works any...

```
foreach ($clasipun as $inde=>$valor){
  //at $inde=1 I receive a $valor=0.33333333333333
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Javier! I think there's more to this than meets the eye. Try just this: `$clasipun = explode(",","0.11111111111111,0.22222222222222,0.33333333333333");
echo $clasipun[1];` (in an online php editor, for example) and you get the `0.22222...` result, as you would expect.

Comment: What does `var_dump($clasipun);` give you?

Comment: see things are working as expected https://3v4l.org/tsTuY

Comment: Is there more code that is not included in the question because it didn't seem relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, thanks for yours time.

Yesterday it must have been obfuscated, but the problem was in the "asort", which orders the content but keeps the keys. fix.

```
$clasipun = explode(",","0.11111111111111,0.33333333333333,0.22222222222222");
echo $clasipun[1]; //Receive 0.33333333333333
asort($clasipun);
echo $clasipun[1];//Receive 0.33333333333333
sort($clasipun);
echo $clasipun[1];//Receive 0.22222222222222 !fine
```

Take a look at this:

```
$clasipun = explode(",","0.11111111111111,0.33333333333333,0.22222222222222");
var_dump($clasipun);
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "0.11111111111111"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "0.33333333333333"
        [2]=>
        string(16) "0.22222222222222"
       }
asort($clasipun);
var_dump($clasipun);
       array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "0.11111111111111"
        [2]=> <-!!!!!!!!!!!
        string(16) "0.22222222222222"
        [1]=> <-!!!!!!!!!!
        string(16) "0.33333333333333"
        }
sort($clasipun);
var_dump($clasipun);
       array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "0.11111111111111"
        [1]=> <-!!!!!!!!!!!
        string(16) "0.22222222222222"
        [2]=> <-!!!!!!!!!!
        string(16) "0.33333333333333"
        }
```

The problem is that not to make the explode of a direct string, it was a variable that contained the string, and to make the implode, as ordered by the asort, the new string if it came out in the correct order. What a mistake.

Solved...